# How should I check parameters in my func to be an integer or float?

Tags: python, function, input, parameters

```
def sum_of_max(*args):
    my_list = list(args)
    first_max = max(my_list)
    my_list.remove(max(my_list))
    return first_max + max(my_list)

print(sum_of_max( "qwerty", 1, 6))
```

**Question:**
How should I check parameters in my func to be an integer or float?

Comment: What do you want to do in that case? Isn't the `TypeError` exception enough?

Comment: That depends on what you want to *do* if they aren't all comparable. I'd argue a mix of `int` and `float` values is fine, because can compare an `int` to a `float`. But you can't compare a `str` to either, so do you want to silently ignore  such values, or do you just want to raise an error (which `max` will already do, so you can catch that or simply let it propagate up the call stack).?

Comment: `+` will also raise an exception if it turns out you can't add the two largest values.

Comment: Yes, i want to know how to work with *args and exceptions in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option could be:

```
def sum_of_max(*args):
    if not all(type(x) in (float, int) for x in args):
        raise TypeError("Parameters should be of type 'int' or 'float'")

    my_list = list(args)
    first_max = max(my_list)
    my_list.remove(max(my_list))
    return first_max + max(my_list)

print(sum_of_max( "qwerty", 1, 6))
# Output: TypeError: Parameters should be of type 'int' or 'float'
```

But it is only replacing the exception raised by `max()` with a more explicit one. The best option is probably to keep your function as is and to catch a potential error when using it:

```
try:
    print(sum_of_max("qwerty", 1, 6))
except ValueError:
    # Do what you want in case of ValueError
```

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Your function shouldn't really care about the type of values it gets. What it *does* care about is:

1. All the values in the list can be compared to each other
2. The two largest values can be added together.

The simplest thing to do is to *assume* these are true, and let any exceptions raised by `>` or `+` to propagate; whoever called `sum_of_max` can catch those and deal with them, either by fixing the argument and calling `sum_of_max` again or supplying some default value in place of what `sum_of_max` might have returned. This is actually easier to do without using `max`, but iterating over the arguments yourself.

```
def sum_of_max(*args):
    biggest = None
    second_biggest = None
    for x in args:
        if biggest is None or x > biggest:
            biggest = x
            second_biggest = biggest
    return biggest + second_biggest
```

Note that one case in which `biggest + second_biggest` will raise an exception is if there aren't at least two comparable values, in which case one or both will never be assigned a value other than `None`.